# Why do I have to always run ssh-add when using buildx --mount=type=ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, docker

docker help wanted

docker build `--mount=type=ssh` is only working for me after I do `ssh-add` on my host machine
Is it because I have something miss configured?

here are the outputs of running and image with the following line `RUN --mount=type=ssh ssh -vT git@github.com`

BEFORE `ssh-add`, it doesn't work
https://pastebin.com/KgsfujVy

AFTER `shh-add`, it does work
https://pastebin.com/ep914vyN

and my ssh config file

```bsh
❯ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Why is this?
I do not want to have to run `ssh-add` on every start up or have to add it to my `~.profile`

Comment: Is the keyfile protected by a passphrase?

Comment: Nope, it is not